# Play framework : software caused connection abort : recv failed

Tags: playframework-2.5

I downloaded Play Framework 2.5.x with java 1.8 a few days back and I am trying to run a new app. I created the app through the Ligthbend Activator UI, but when I go to the folder where that new app is and type the command activator I receive errors such as :

[error] Server access Error: Software caused connection abort: recv failed url=
https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.sonatype.sisu/sisu-guice/3.1.0/jars/sisu-guice.jar

This only happens when I am connected to my office internet.  When trying from home I am able to run this command without issue.

Any ideas what is causing this and any possible workarounds.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a proxy/firewall issue to me, you can set proxy creds using JAVA_OPTS

Comment: Is there anyway to download this jar files to my machine so that it does not need to access them through the firewall?

Comment: There is the offline distribution you can try https://downloads.typesafe.com/typesafe-activator/1.3.10/typesafe-activator-1.3.10.zip (2.5.4 link)